# Magento 2 - custom admin grid field - error when sorting or filtering

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, custom, uicomponent

I added a custom column to the admin grid, like this

```
<column name="customer_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\CustomerName">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

In my CustomerName class I create values for this column:

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
    foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($item['customer_id']);
        $name = $customer ? $customer->getFirstName().' <'.$customer->getEmail().'>' : '';
        $item[$fieldName] = $name;
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

It shows in the grid as expected. But when I try to sort by this column or filter - an error occurred

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_name' in 'order clause'
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Now I try to resolve this problem by deleting CustomerName class (and remove reference to it in column tag in XML) and instead I added the _renderFiltersBefore() function in my collection class

```
 protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
     $joinTable = $this->getTable('customer_entity');
     $this->getSelect()->join($joinTable.' as customer_entity','main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id', array('*'));
     $this->getSelect()->columns('CONCAT(firstname," <",email,">") as customer_name');
     parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

Now sorting is working, but filtering does not (get the same error)

Answer (score 14):

There is a factory method that you can use, and this is the `addFilterToMap()`. Where Magento 2 rendering filter just replace the subjects of the conditions based on the mapped fields

you can call it either in *_initSelect* or *_renderFiltersBefore* method.

for a simple column which already existing in the selection (good to resolve ambiguous errors)

```
$this
     ->addFilterToMap('customer_id', 'ce.entity_id');
```

but in your case need to map an expression as

```
$this
    ->addFilterToMap(
       'customer_name ', 
       new \Zend_Db_Expr('CONCAT(ce.firstname," <",ce.email,">")')
    );
```

so the condition part of the query will be

````
... WHERE (CONCAT(ce.firstname," <",ce.email,">") LIKE '%@yippie.com%') ...
``` instead of
````

... WHERE (customer_name LIKE '%@yippie.com%') ...

```
also, you can use another collection related factory method to use expressions in the `SELECT` part of the query

    $this
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'firstname',
            new \Zend_Db_Expr('CONCAT(ce.firstname," <",ce.email,">")'),
            []
        )

instead of 

    $this->getSelect()->columns('CONCAT(ce.firstname," <",ce.email,">") as firstname');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was struggling with this for half a day. Where did you find/learn this? Surely, not in the docs?

Comment: as the original post mentioned: had to add custom column to admin grid - with filter and sort options. Cost about 1.5 days to figure it out _(ofc with least footprint)_

Comment: I'm trying to display the both invoice and sale order increment_ids on my custom module admin grid with sale order increment id is relabeled as 'ordincrementid'.  Still even i had used the addFilterToMap(); i'm unable to filter the sale order increment_id. It returning this error => Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 8):

It took some time, but I figured this out

In my xml listing:

```
<column name="firstname">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

In Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SomeCustomModel\Grid:

```
/**
 * adding email to customer name column
 */
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['ce' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
        'main_table.customer_id = ce.entity_id',
        ['*']
    );

    $this->getSelect()->columns('CONCAT(ce.firstname," <",ce.email,">") as firstname');
    return $this;
}
```

In Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SomeCustomModel

```
/**
 * addding ability to filter by column with customer name and email
 */
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $wherePart = $this->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
    foreach ($wherePart as $key => $cond) {
        $wherePart[$key] = str_replace('`firstname`', 'CONCAT(firstname," <",email,">")', $cond);
    }
    $this->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $wherePart);
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```