# Admin Grid filter for Custom table Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3, magento-admin

I have created a table with columns like patient_first_name, patient_last_name etc, I am able to get them in an Admin Grid Column.

```
<column name="patient_first_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PatientName">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Patient Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Inside the class, I concat first name and last name to display them in a single column in the admin grid using.

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $items['patient_first_name'] = $items['patient_first_name']." ".$items['patient_last_name'];
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
```

So this does its job to display the first name and last name together in the grid column, but when I use any filter to say, `John Doe` it searches only the `patient_first_name` column, which is correct since it is mapped that particular column but since the values would be stored as John in `patient_first_name` column and Doe in `patient_last_name` column, it will not return any result.

I used this solution to join both first and last names and show them together.
[How can I merge columns in UI grid in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205028/how-can-i-merge-columns-in-ui-grid-in-magento-2)
The issue comes that when you add a filter Magento tries to look for a particular column in Db, so I can't use something like patient_name and was getting the same error as here [Magento 2 - custom admin grid field - error when sorting or filtering](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126207/magento-2-custom-admin-grid-field-error-when-sorting-or-filtering)

I have tried _renderFiltersBefore but the issue with select remains.

I want to know a way how I can override the filter and write my own method which gives a select searching both first name and last name.

Answer (score 0):

In listing xml, inside < filters > tag

```
<filterRange name=""amount"" class=""Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\AmountRange"" />
```

In Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\AmountRange.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Filters\Type;
class AmountRange extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\Range
{

/**
 * Apply filter by its type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $value
 * @return void
 */
  protected function applyFilterByType($type, $value)
  {

        $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setConditionType($type)
            ->setField($this->getName())
            ->setValue($value)
            ->create();

        $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addFilter($filter);

  }
}
```